# Finitely presented group in which every element is conjugate to its square

Tags: gr.group-theory, gt.geometric-topology

Does there exist a nontrivial finitely presented group in which every element is conjugate to its square? Is this an open problem?

Motivation: Jahren proved in [Geom Dedicata (2010)] that if $M$ is a closed manifold of dimension $\ge 5$ such that $\pi_1(M)$ has an element not conjugate to its square, then the smooth pseudoisotopy space for $M$ is not connected.

Finitely generated examples exist: Osin  [constructed](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0411039) a f.g. infinite torsion free group in which all nontrivial elements are conjugate.

Comment: A couple of remarks: $Homeo^+(R)$ has this property, so one could look for a finitely-presented subgroup (something like Thompson's groups) which might also have this property? Also, such a group is perfect (in fact, every element is a commutator) and has no finite quotients. Is there a well-known finitely-presented infinite group in which every element is a commutator?

Comment: More infinitely generated examples similar to $Homeo(\mathbb R)$ can be found in http://www.scirp.org/journal/PaperDownload.aspx?paperID=3283

Answer (score 1):

One is naturally led to consider the simple case, and I wonder if Graham Higman's 1951 examples might suffice.  In *J. Lond. Math. Soc.* **26** (1951), 61-64, Higman gives examples of groups presented using 4 generators with 4 relations.  (One can replace 4 by a larger integer.)  According to these relations, each of the four generators is conjugate to its square.  Of course, this is no guarantee that *every* group element has this property.  Maybe someone can add why Higman's examples do or do not answer the question.

Comment: 1) This Higman group doesn't work: it has an action on a tree with hyperbolic elements. Such a hyperbolic element $g$ cannot be conjugate to their square, because if $L$ is its displacement length then the displacement of $g^2$ is $2L$, whence $L=0$.

Comment: 2) As long as the question concerns finitely presented groups, it is *not* true that one is led to the simple case (because any nontrivial fg group has a simple quotient, but for a finitely presented group, one does not necessarily get a finitely presented simple quotient); actually Miller's group (an infinite f.p. group all of whose nontrivial quotients have a nonsolvable word problem) has no finitely presented simple quotient at all.